# Producing a clickable function from a loop

Tags: javascript, loops, onclick

I'm *very* new to Javascript (and programming in general), so please forgive me if this is a silly question:

I have the following loop that produces a `div` for every item in an array:

```
for (i=0;i<inventory.length;i++)
{
    document.getElementById('inventoryitems').innerHTML += "<div class='itemblock'>" + inventory[i] + "</div>";
}
```

I want each item to be able to pass a variable (its name in the array, ideally) to a function called `useItem(itemName)` when clicked. Anyone have any ideas how I should go about doing that? I tried

```
document.getElementById('inventoryitems').innerHTML += "<div class='itemblock'>" + inventory[i] + "</div>";
inventory[i].onclick = useItem(inventory[i]);
```

and

```
document.getElementById('inventoryitems').innerHTML += "<div class='itemblock' onClick='useItem(" + inventory[i] + ")'>" + inventory[i] + "</div>";
```

But neither appear to work. Any help you fine folks can offer is most appreciated.

EDIT: Thank you all SO much for the quick answers! I decided to go with Kamil's solution. Thanks again, everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var items = document.getElementsByClassName("item");

for(i =0;i< items.length;i++){
    items[i].onclick = function(){
        useItem(this);
    };
}

function useItem(el){
  alert(el.innerHTML);
}
```

and here you can try how it works: http://jsfiddle.net/Q3AYC/

Comment: this answer is way better than mine.

Answer (score 0):

The DOM doesn't know which element is tied to which click event, so nothing will happen. What happens if you add an id field to your div elements?

```
"<div class='itemblock' id=" + inventory[i] + ">" + inventory[i] + "</div>"
```

This, of course is provided that all of your inventory items are unique. Let me know if this works.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally do the following:

```
for (i=0;i<inventory.length;i++) {
    document.getElementById('inventoryitems').innerHTML += "<div class='itemblock'>" + inventory[i] + "</div>";
     inventory[i].onclick = useItem;
}
```

This will pass the actual element to the `useItem` function which can then be found in the array through `inventory.indexOf( this )` or just get the contents through `this.innerHTML` within the `useItem` function.

The reason why your `inventory[i].onclick = useItem(inventory[i]);` did not work was that it was calling your `useItem` function during the assignment rather than just telling it to call the function during a click.

If this is not sufficient, please give me more context to your problem and I would be happy to help further.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the basics of it the loop use querySelectorAll to grab a list of items you want to iterate through then you add the click event.  IE8 has a different event model attachEvent so you will need to use an if statement. but thats the basics

```
 <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="clickable">01</div>
        <div class="clickable">02</div>
        <div class="clickable">03</div>
        <div class="clickable">04</div>
        <div class="clickable">05</div>
    </body>
    </html>

<script>

    function addEvent(element, evt, fn){
        //fn is a function
        //evt is your event
        if(window.addEventListener){

            element.addEventListener(evt, fn, false);

        } else {
            //IE8
            element.attachEvent("on" + evt, fn);

        }

    }

    var func = function(){ alert("hello") };

    var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".clickable");
    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){

        addEvent(elements[i], "click", func);
        elements[i].innerHTML = "content added " + i;

    }

</script>
```